# Why is dp/dv zero for a real gas in critical conditions?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

I have read this fact in various websites but cannot understand the reason. What is an intuitive explanation of this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is merely a *shard* of a fact which does not make much sense in and by itself. After all, in systems with gas/liquid equilibrium there is nothing really special about $\left(\dfrac{\partial\mathfrak p}{\partial V}\right)_T=0$. On the contrary, this is pretty typical. See all those points where the blue lines (isotherms) are horizontal? They make up a whole huge area on the diagram.

[image: real gas isotherms]
([source](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/png520/m3_p3.html))

Indeed, if you have a liquid in equilibrium with its saturated vapor, then the pressure does not depend on volume (in an isothermal processes, that is). As you compress it a little more, some gas turns to liquid; as you release it, some liquid evaporates. The pressure still remains the same - namely, the saturated vapor pressure at given temperature. Things start changing only when you pull the piston all the way out or push it all the way in.

Now, the two-phase area, huge as it is, does not comprise *all* diagram. If you heat the gas past the critical temperature, you'll get an isotherm of a different sort (it is *not* shown on the picture, so just imagine one, positioned above the rest of them). It will be all smooth and monotonic, ***without*** those horizontal parts.

Well, then there must be a temperature where this behavior changes, and that's what we call the critical temperature. Sure enough, it produces a very special isotherm: there is only one point on it where $\left(\dfrac{\partial\mathfrak p}{\partial V}\right)_T=0$. (That's what we call the critical point, BTW.) Moreover, since it is an inflection point, it also has $\left(\dfrac{\partial^2\mathfrak p}{\partial V^2}\right)_T=0$. Now ***that's*** the fact one should remember about the critical point.

The peculiar behavior of pretty much all physical properties around the critical point gives rise to various weird phenomena like [critical opalescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_opalescence), but that's another story.

So it goes.